# Exception when handling Window Alert Dialogs

Tags: java, selenium, autoit

[image: Alert dialog]I need to handle Windows alert dialog,clicking leave page button in the dialog should navigate from the page. I have used AutoIT script and referenced the exe in my Java code, but when the alert is displayed I see

`"exception waitforpageload : [JavaScript Error: "a.document.getElementsByTagName(...)[0].getButton is not a function"`

error and browser quits. Kindly help me in fixing this. Below is the AutoIT script and Java code referencing the Exe.

AutoIT script:

```
WinWaitActive("MyONE - Mozilla Firefox","","1000")
Sleep(70000)
 If WinExists("MyONE - Mozilla Firefox") Then

Send("{ENTER}")
 EndIf
```

Java Code:

```
     Thread.sleep(20000);
     Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/TestProject - DEV/test.exe");
```

Comment: Have you tested your AutoIT script without selenium code?

Comment: Yes, I have  tested and it's working fine.

Comment: Post a bigger snippet of Java code, I want to see at which position you are calling the autoit exe.

Comment: Actually I have written method to call this exe after clicking on a link in the website, so when the link is clicked, the next step will call  the method.           {public void CLICKONNEXTCONFIRMATION(WebDriver driver) {
 
  try {
      Thread.sleep(20000);
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/TestProject - DEV/test.exe");
   
         resultDetails.setFlag(true);
         
     } catch (Exception e) {
              
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }

Comment: Try swapping the calls, i.e., call CLICKONNEXTCONFIRMATION this first and then the line of code which is just previous to this.

Comment: That will not work, cuz the alert display only after clicking the link written previous to the method, calling the method before will not work

Comment: Vikas, attached is the alert what I'm seeing, need to handle that. Thanks!

Comment: Please try that. Because AutoIT script always need to be called up in advance. So that it is already running when that popup is displayed.

Comment: Vikas, actually the alert dialog was displayed as web alert when running the scripts, wonder how :)  so I was able to handle using driver.switchto().alert().accept(). Its working fine, thanks for your comments!

Comment: Haha, you wasted a lot of your efforts writing AutoIT code.